# Print a 1-D slice of a numpy array vertically

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to print a vertical slice of a numpy array so it displays vertically but it always prints horizontally.
Given this square array:

```
a = np.ones([5,5])
```

I've tried:

```
print a[:,1]
print np.reshape(a[:,1], (1,-1))
print a[:,1].T
print [a[:,1].T]
```

which give me:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]
```

I want to see:

```
[[1],
 [1],
 [1],
 [1], 
 [1]]
```

Comment: While `a` is 2d, `a[:,1]` is 1d (you removed a dimension).  Transpose of a 1d is still 1d.  You have to preserve or add a dimension back on.

Comment: @ayhan's answer was good enough to accept.  Consider up voting as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new axis:

```
a[:, 1, None]
Out: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

or

```
a[:, 1, np.newaxis]
Out: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Comment: And sometimes you want to add an axis on the end without specifying the number of dimensions (say an image array that could be 3D or 2D) in which case you can use an ellipsis a[..., None]

Answer (score 1):

I'd wrap the second indexer in brackets

```
a[:, [1]]

array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add a dimension:

```
a[:,1:2]
Out:
array([[ 1.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`np.vstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
print(np.vstack(a[:,1]))
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just an alternative, I sometimes use `atleast_2d`:

```
np.atleast_2d(a[:, 1]).T
```

(there are also `atleast_1d`, `atleast_3d` options too)